# Syntax Highlighting for R in Macvim

Tags: r, vim, editor, syntax-highlighting, macvim

I use R and I find some of the embedded editor's characteristics annoying. Typically, it would be convenient to have the possibility to add tabs or even bette to do splits like you can do it with vim.

I have a Mac running Mavericks and I use Macvim. I want to use vim as my R editor, without using it as an IDE.

However, the syntax highlighting is not convincing. The functions are not recognized for instance.

I installed the Vim-R-plugin (I followed [these instructions](http://www.r-bloggers.com/vim-r-plugin-installation/)). However, I found no change in my syntax highlighting.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Apparently syntax highlighting of the VIm-R-Plugin does not work with Macvim... [See Here](http://www.lepem.ufc.br/jaa/r-plugin.html)

Comment: Syntax highlighting work fine in my case with MacVim and vim-r-plugin. But it work better using iTerm + tmux + vim-r-plugin because it's possible to connect vim and R. Could you show us your .vimrc maybe? What version of Vim are you using? Maybe you have to force the 256 colors with
if &term =~ "xterm" || &term =~ "256" || $DISPLAY != "" || $HAS_256_COLORS == "yes"
    set t_Co=256
endif

Answer (score -1):

[R-Studio](http://www.rstudio.com/) is a development environment for R. It is very light and powerful and it offers some embedded themes to highlight code.

You can use it as editor only...

Comment: Syntax highlighting in R studio is not great either, it does not recognized the  built-in functions...

Comment: it's true, it depends on the built-in theme you choose...
I selected the "cobalt" theme and it do not recognize strings, but the other themes make it well!

Comment: UPDATE: I don't know if you solved your problem, but I discovered that using R-Studio Version 0.99.902 you can highlight functions in:
Tools -> Global Options -> Code -> Display -> "Highlight R function calls"
It works very well!!! ^^
Hope this can help!
Bye, 
Inzirio